# Every $\sigma$-finite measure is absolutely continuous w.r.t. some finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I'm trying to prove below theorem mentioned in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434463/does-l-p-mu-x-l-q-mu-x-hold-for-sigma-finite-measure-spaces?noredirect=1#comment1119171_434463). This theorem allows us to generalize [this property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4506013/368425) from finite measure spaces to $\sigma$-finite measure spaces.

> **Theorem:** Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. There is a finite measure $\nu$ on $(X, \mathcal A)$ such that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\nu$.

Could you have a check on my bellow attempt?

---

**Proof:** Let $(X_m)$ be a countable measurable partition of $X$ such that $\mu(X_m) <\infty$. We define a measure $\mu_n$ by
$$
\mu_n (A) :=  \mu(A \cap X_m) \quad \forall A \in \mathcal A.
$$

Then $\mu_n$ is finite and supported on $X_n$. We define a measure $\nu_n$ by
$$
\nu_n(A) := \frac{\mu_n(A)}{2^{n}\mu_n(X_n)}.
$$

Then $\mu_n \ll \nu_n$ and $\nu_n(X) = 2^{-n}$. By [Radon–Nikodym theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538795/a-proof-of-radon-nikodym-theorem), there is  a measurable function $f_n:X \to [0, \infty)$ such that
$$
\mu_n(A) = \int_A f \mathrm d \nu_n(A) \quad \forall A \in \mathcal A.
$$

Because $\nu_n$ is supported on $X_n$, we can assume $f_n=0$ on $X \setminus X_n$. Let $f := \sum_n f_n$. Then $f$ is the Radon–Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ w.r.t. $\nu :=\sum_n \nu_n$. Notice that
$$
\nu(X) = \sum_n \nu_n(X_n) = \sum_n 2^{-n} = 1.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: you may want to assume (w.l.o.g) that $0<\mu(A)m)<\infty$ to avoid division by $0$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz You're right! I was sloppy.