# Every $\sigma$-finite measure has a strictly positive density w.r.t. some finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Previously, I proved that

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4575991/every-sigma-finite-measure-is-absolutely-continuous-w-r-t-some-finite-measur) There is a finite measure $\nu$ on $(X, \mathcal A)$ such that $\mu$ has a [density](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_derivative)  $f:X \to [0, \infty)$ w.r.t. $\nu$.

Now I would like to strengthen above result, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** There is a finite measure $\nu$ on $(X, \mathcal A)$ such that $\mu$ has a **positive** density $f:X \to (0, \infty)$ w.r.t. $\nu$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof:** Let $(f, \nu)$ be given by the **Lemma**. Let $N := f^{-1} (0)$. Because $f$ is measurable, $N \in \mathcal A$. This means $N$ is a $\mu$-null set. Let $N^c := X \setminus N$ and we define a measure $\lambda$ by
$$
\lambda(A) := \nu (A \cap N^c) \quad \forall A \in \mathcal A.
$$

Then $\lambda$ is concentrated on $N^c$. We define $g:X \to (0, \infty)$ by
$$
g(x) :=
\begin{cases}
f(x) &\text{if} &x \in N^c \\
1 &\text{if} &x \in N.
\end{cases}
$$

Then

- $\lambda$ is a finite and $g$ measurable.
- $f$ and $g$ agree on $N^c$.
- $\nu$ and $\lambda$ agree on the sub $\sigma$-algebra of $N^c$.
- $\lambda = 0$ on the sub $\sigma$-algebra of $N$.

As such, for every $A \in \mathcal A$ we have
$$
\mu (A) = \int_A f \mathrm d \nu = \int_{A \cap N^c} f \mathrm d \nu = \int_{A \cap N^c} g \mathrm d \lambda = \int_A g \mathrm d \lambda.
$$

As such, the pair $(g, \lambda)$ satisfies our requirement. This completes the proof.