# Generalize Theorem 1. in Diestel/Uhl's Vector Measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, radon-nikodym

I'm reading *Theorem 1* at page 98 of *Vector Measures* by Joseph Diestel, John Jerry Uhl. Here we use the [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space).

> **Theorem 1** Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a **finite** measure space, $1 \leq p<\infty$, and $(X, |\cdot|)$ be a Banach space. Then $L_{p}(\mu, X)^*=L_{q} (\mu, X^*)$ where $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$, if and only if $X^{*}$ has the [Radon-Nikodým property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546633/construct-conditional-expectation-on-banach-spaces-with-radon-nikod%c3%bdm-property) with respect to $\mu$.

I'm trying to extend above result to $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. The idea of the proof is from [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434463/does-l-p-mu-x-l-q-mu-x-hold-for-sigma-finite-measure-spaces#comment1119171_434463) by @JochenWengenroth.

Could you have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much for your help!

---

**Proof:** Let $\mu$ be $\sigma$-finite. We need the following lemma as a bridge, i.e.,

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576316/every-sigma-finite-measure-has-a-strictly-positive-density-w-r-t-some-finite) Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. There is a finite measure $\nu$ on $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ such that $\mu$ has a density $f:X \to (0, \infty)$ w.r.t. $\nu$.

Let $(f, \nu)$ be given by the **Lemma**. By **Theorem 1**, there is an isometric isomorphism
$$
\varphi: L_{p}(\nu, X)^* \to L_{q} (\nu, X^*).
$$

Notice that
$$
g \in L_{p}(\nu, X) \iff \int |g|^p \mathrm d \nu = \int  |f^{-1/p}g|^p \mathrm d \mu <\infty \iff f^{-1/p}g \in L_{p}(\mu, X). \quad (\star)
$$

We define
$$
\psi: L_{p}(\mu, X)^* \to L_{p}(\nu, X)^*
$$
by
$$
\psi(H) (g) = H (f^{-1/p}g) \quad \forall H \in L_{p}(\mu, X)^*, \forall g \in L_{p}(\nu, X).
$$

It follows from $(\star)$ that $\psi$ is an isometric isomorphism. Again,
$$
g \in L_{q}(\nu, X^*) \iff \int |g|^q \mathrm d \nu = \int  |f^{-1/q}g|^q \mathrm d \mu <\infty \iff f^{-1/q}g \in L_{q}(\mu, X). \quad (\star\star)
$$

We define
$$
\phi: L_{q} (\nu, X^*) \to L_{q} (\mu, X^*), g \mapsto f^{-1/q}g.
$$

It follows from $(\star\star)$ that $\phi$ is an isometric isomorphism. As such,
$$
\phi \circ \varphi \circ \psi : L_{p}(\mu, X)^* \to L_{q} (\mu, X^*).
$$
is an isometric isomorphism . This completes the proof.

Comment: This looks fine.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you so much for your help! Your lemma is new to me and very useful.